# Detecting "load" or "done" event after setting new CartoCSS using set() in cartodb.js

Tags: carto, carto-js

I'm loading a map data tilelayer onto a Leaflet map using cartodb.

Upon user input, the map reconfigures its CartoCSS to display data differently. Example below.

```
layer.on({
    click: function(e){
        dataLayer.getSubLayer(0).set({
            cartocss: "#export { polygon-opacity: 0; }"         
        }).on("load", function(){ console.log("load"); });
     }
});
```

I'd like to be able to detect when the reconfigured layer has loaded -- there's sometimes a considerable lag -- with a "done" or "load" event. But neither works as drafted above, and the documentation doesn't give any hints as to any special promise/event for `.set()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load events seems to be supported (but aren't documented) on the dataLayer, but since promises aren't supported you would would have to setup the listener before you call the `set`, e.g:

`dataLayer.on("load", function() {
  console.log('layer changed');
});
dataLayer.getSubLayer(0).set({
  cartocss: "#export { polygon-opacity: 0; }"

});`